# Python/C "defs" file - what is it?

Tags: python, c

In the nautilus-python bindings, there is a file "[nautilus.defs](http://git.gnome.org/browse/nautilus-python/tree/src/nautilus.defs)". It contains stanzas like

```
(define-interface MenuProvider
  (in-module "Nautilus")
  (c-name "NautilusMenuProvider")
  (gtype-id "NAUTILUS_TYPE_MENU_PROVIDER")
)
```

or

```
(define-method get_mime_type
  (of-object "NautilusFileInfo")
  (c-name "nautilus_file_info_get_mime_type")
  (return-type "char*")
)
```

Now I can see what most of these do (eg. that last one means that I can call the method "get_mime_type" on a "FileInfo" object). But I'd like to know: what is this file, exactly (ie. what do I search the web for to find out more info)? Is it a common thing to find in Python/C bindings? What is the format, and where is it documented? What program actually processes it?

(So far, I've managed to glean that it gets [transformed into a C source file](http://git.gnome.org/browse/nautilus-python/tree/src/Makefile.am#n37), and it looks a bit like lisp to me.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your "What program actually processes it?" question:

From `Makefile.in` in the `src` directory, the command that translates the `.defs` file into C is `PYGTK_CODEGEN`.  To find out what `PYGTK_CODEGEN` is, look in the top-level `configure.in` file, which contains these lines:

```
AC_MSG_CHECKING(for pygtk codegen)
PYGTK_CODEGEN="$PYTHON `$PKG_CONFIG --variable=codegendir pygtk-2.0`/codegen.py"
AC_SUBST(PYGTK_CODEGEN)
AC_MSG_RESULT($PYGTK_CODEGEN)
```

So the program that processes it is a Python script called codegen.py, that apparently has some link with `PyGTK`.  Now a Google search for `PyGTK codegen` gives me [this link](http://wiki.laptop.org/go/PyGTK-Codegen) as the first hit, which says:

"PyGTK-Codegen is a system for automatically generating wrappers for interfacing GTK code with Python."

and also gives some examples.

As for: "What is the format, and where is it documented?".  As others have said, the code looks a lot like simple Scheme.  I couldn't find any documentation at all on `codegen` on the PyGTK site;  this looks like one of those many dark corners of open source that isn't well documented.  Your best bet would probably be to download a recent tarball for `PyGTK`, look through the sources for the `codegen.py` file and see if the file itself contains sufficient documentation.

Comment: Safyan's answer was good too, but I appreciated the deductive breakdown :)

Answer (score 3):

All you need to create Python bindings for C code is to use the [Python / C API](http://docs.python.org/extending/). However, the API can be somewhat repetitive and redundant, and so various forms of automation may be used to create them. For example, you may have heard of [swig](http://www.swig.org/). The LISP-like (Scheme) code that you see is simply a configuration file for [PyGTK-Codegen](http://wiki.laptop.org/go/PyGTK-Codegen), which is a similar automation program for creating bindings to Python.